# An old Q but no solution for me yet: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

It's an old question, searched a lot online, but no solution working for me yet.
iMac, java 1.8.0, MySql 5.7.24

Just setup a java workspace from repo, was building fine and deploying fine to local, using intellij.

This morning i continued to play more, there was multiple things e.g. i cannot login to the mysql from command line
mysql -u root -p, while Java workspace seems to be fine.

so i used

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD("newpass");
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit
```

to reset password

Everything is fine with mysql command line now.
I went to intellij updated the password, clicked "Test Connection", and it's successful.

Then i went to rebuild my java workspace, passed.

The problem comes when i try to deploy to local machine, 
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
This is the same error when i run

```
mysql -u root
```

When i run

```
mysql -u root -p
```

i can login after typing the password.

The confusing part is, i thought i saved password in intellij, "Test Connection" passed, why java deploy still failing ?

i did add .my.cnf, now from command line 
mysql -u root
works, not my java deployment.

Sorry i've trying everything i can think of, not sure how to report clearly.

Comment: This `SET PASSWORD` approach with `PASSWORD()` is not the way I'd suggest doing this. Do [`SET PASSWORD FOR ... REPLACE '...'`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-password.html)

Comment: I assume its a spring app. How are you deploying your code on the local server? Are you passing in the right profile name? Does the property files have correct credentials?

Comment: @tadman mysql is 5.7, i tested that SET PASSWORD with "mysql -u root -p", it works

Comment: @raviiii1 it's spring app, i'm new to spring, all i know is everything was working for java app before i change the mysql password

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-password.html) the syntax for `SET PASSWORD` is:

```
SET PASSWORD 'root' REPLACE '...'
```

Comment: my sql is 5.7, still old syntax. Finally it's a place in my java project config, we save db password in that config and i didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

sorry it's my bad, our java project has another config file which holds the db password, i didn't know about that till now ...